# Dimension of a solution set (Counter example)

Tags: linear-algebra

I have the felling that the following statement is false:

Given an homogeneous system of linear equations expressed as:

$$
A \vec{x} = \vec{0}
$$

where $A$ has dimensions $n \times m$ with entries on R or C. Where m < n. Then the dimension of the solution set is always $n-m$.

My question at the end is, how could I cook a counterexample.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If $A=0$, then the dimension of the solution set is $m$.
More generally, the solution set has dimension $m-s$, where $s$ is the dimension of the vector space spanned by $L_1,...L_n$ the lines of $A$.

In fact $s$ is the number of **independent** equations, which is intuitive.